# What iPhone SDK control is this?

Tags: iphone

Can anybody tell me what the following control is called?

[iPhone control http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/6615/checkcontrol.png](http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/6615/checkcontrol.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a standard control, but you could make one with a UIButton with custom images.